# How do I link a PS4 user account to a child profile?

Tags: ps4

I bought a Playstation 4 for my child's birthday; they were previously using mine. Now, I can't seem to figure out how to link their child profile (found in Family Management) to this new system. My only options appear to be to create a duplicate child account, which means losing their trophies and other data. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to create a new user on the PS4 (local account) for the child - [this should be fairly straight forward](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vp_xr255ocw). Once a new user is created, you can then sign into the existing PSN Account.

If you run into issues around "Family Manager" or similar, you may need to first add yourself on to the console by creating a User on the PS4 and signing into your own PSN Account, and then following the above steps to add your child and their existing PSN account.